PostgreSQL request by description
I have two tables - features and tags. In tags table I have id_banner, tag_list, features_id columns. And in features column features. Those tables are externally bind by features column (features - mother, tags - son). I have request to update tags, and features by id_banner, where features can be: equal to the available or different. Need help to make postgres code request
I tried this code:
ALTER TABLE tags
DROP CONSTRAINT tags_features_id_fkey;

UPDATE tags 
SET features_id = $2
  , tag_list = $3 
WHERE id_banner = $1;

ALTER TABLE tags
  ADD CONSTRAINT tags_features_id_fkey 
  FOREIGN KEY (features_id) REFERENCES features(features) 
  ON DELETE CASCADE;

The error:
You cannot insert multiple commands into a prepared statement

I can't make much sense of your text.  Can you provide a DB Fiddle with example data?  You should not be dropping constraints as a matter of normal database operation.  That implies your schema doesn't match your data very well

Prepared statements don’t work anyway on DDL statements like ALTER.

In its current form, the question doesn't explain how its related to the go language but I'm guessing the error was caused by how you attempted to run these queries from a go app. Please add the go part of code to show the full context. It'd also be helpful to see what some mock/sample rows would look like in these tables before and after what you're trying to do. Right now all 3 statements are perfectly valid on their own and it's not really clear why you're lifting the constraint just to update that one table, or what exactly you're trying to achieve.

In PostgreSQL, you cannot execute multiple commands (such as ALTER TABLE with UPDATE) directly in a single prepared statementn they are intended for single SQL commands.
If you need to update tags based on id_banner and  update features, you'll likely need to separate the logic into different steps.
